# Bootstrap—make page unresponsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, scale

Right now I am in a kind of awkward position since have created a website using bootstrap 4 (with compass as ruby gem), but since there is a lot of discussion about the look of that on mobile devices just started right now, the client is now asking me to make the page behave like an »old-school« unresponsive Website, which just scales into the browser, as all the old-fashioned websites do, if they are not responsive by design.

So I removed the the

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and the page is mostly doing as it should. But unfortunately it doesn't work on smaller sizes (> 500px), so I am asking myself which values I need to tweak, that it will just scale down everything.

Right now it works, except for paragraphs (`<p>`), headlines and all other stuff behaves as it should.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling to a CDN, bring the file locally, go in and remove all media queries.

**EDIT** [Check out Bootstrap for the actual removal of responsiveness documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive)

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score -1):

Remove bootstrap css file linking from `<link rel="stylesheet"...`

assuming you don't use bootstrap components (considering styles by bootstrap library)

Comment: then It'll be displayed as same in all devices,That's what you want right?

Comment: I am using the bootstrap ruby gem and compass, so I am importing the parts of bootstrap into my *.scss file. It results in one *.css file. Removing that will remove all styles.